# HSPICE MOSFET parameter

Tags: mosfet, hspice

I want to change a MOSFET parameter (Level 1) in HSPICE.

This image, from *Appendix B: SPICE Device Models and Design and Simulation Examples Using PSpice® and Multisim* of **Microelectronic Circuits** by Sedra and Smith, shows the MOSFET parameters:

[image: Level-1 MOSFET model parameters]

Can I change the MOSFET parameter like this table?

Comment: There should be a help that tells you how to modify the `.model` card for the MOSFET. I don't have HSPICE, but if yo udo then you also have the help file. I would warmly suggest following up some tutorials, and the help will probably have some of those, too.

Answer (score 0):

Just choose the "virtual components" in Multisim and change the SPICE parameters, as in the photo below: [image: change NMOS SPICE parameters]

Comment: The OP was pretty clearly talking about HSPICE, not MultiSim.